# javascript regex camelcase

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I'm currently getting the `location.path` url and display the url as my title, how can I make it camelcase if I have a title of like "banana and apple" I don't want the "and" to be "And" but instead just return "Banana and Apple"

I found this javascript code and its returning my title as "Banana And Apple".

```
function camelize(str) {
        return str.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w|\s+)/g, function(match, index) {
            if (+match === 0) return " "; // or if (/\s+/.test(match)) for white spaces
            return index == 0 ? match.toLowerCase() : match.toUpperCase();
        });
    }
```

and I'm replacing (/) and (-) as space

```
this.title = camelize(lastPartOfUrl.replace(/\/|\-/g, ' '));
```

or

```
var cleanUrl = lastPartOfUrl.replace(/\/-/g, ' ');
this.title = camelize(cleanUrl.replace(/-/g, ' '));
```

Comment: Does that mean that `banana/and/apple-or-orange` should become `Banana and Apple or Orange`?

Comment: How is it supposed to know that "and" is not to be capitalized? By the way, this is not "camelcase", which refers to variable/identifier naming schemes. I guess it would be called "word capitalization".

Answer (score 1):

There is shorter solution based on a single RegEx.

```
function camelCase(txt){
   var lower='and,or,a,in,on,'; //stop-words
   return txt //.split(/\/-/).join(' ')
           .toLowerCase().replace(/(\b.)(\S*\b)(\s|$)/g,
                      function(m/*full match*/,
                               n/*(\b.)*/,
                               p/*(\S*\b)*/,
                               q/*(\s|$)*/){
                        //console.log(n,p);
                        return (lower.indexOf(n+p+',')===-1?
                          n.toUpperCase() : n) + p + q;});
}
```

Comment: This seems to work okay and shorter, I don't get the return txt comment. Is there a way to remove "/" and replace "-" as space in the func? so I don't have to do it separately?

Comment: uncomment `//.split(/\/-/).join(' ')`. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

```js
String.prototype.capitalizeFirstLetter = function() {
  return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
};

String.prototype.toCamelCase = function() {
  return this.split(" ").reduce((previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex) => (currentIndex == 1) ? 
    previousValue.toLowerCase() + currentValue.capitalizeFirstLetter() :
    previousValue + currentValue.capitalizeFirstLetter()
  );
};
alert("Banana And Apples".toCamelCase())
```

**EDIT:** Capitalize words, except for an array of words to become lowercase:

```js
function titleCaseExcept(value, lowerCaseArray, upperCaseArray, isCaseSensitive) {
  var str = value.replace(/([^\W_]+[^\s-]*) */g, (txt) =>
    txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase()
  );
  var regexFlags = (isCaseSensitive) ? 'gi' : 'g';

  // Lower case words
  lowerCaseArray.forEach( (element) => 
    str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\s' + element + '\\s', regexFlags), 
      (text) => text.toLowerCase()
    )
  );
    
  // Upper case words
  upperCaseArray.forEach( (element) =>
    str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + element + '\\b', regexFlags), 
      (text) => text.toUpperCase()
    )
  );
      
  return str;
}

// Find any of these, in any case, to replace to lowercase
lowers = ['A', 'an', 'THE', 'and', 'But', 'oR', 'For', 'Nor', 'As', 'At', 
  'By', 'For', 'From', 'In', 'Into', 'Near', 'Of', 'On', 'Onto', 'To', 'With'];
// Find any of these, in any case, to replace to uppercase
uppers = ['id', 'tv'];

// Last parameter is true for case-insensitive arrays
console.log(upperCaseExcept("Bananas And Apples In Some Place On Tv", lowers, uppers, true));
```

Comment: ...I don't understand your question. So you want every second word not capitalized? Or conjunctives to not be capitalized?

Comment: he wants to replace `And` with `and`

Comment: @RolandStarke Updated with a rather nifty function.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't yet a coherent way of doing this in any computer language unless you resort to Nick Bull's solution, or similar.

The problem is that computer programs don't recognise that 'banana' is a different type of word than 'and' - ie: 'banana' is a noun, 'and' is a conjunction.

You either have to use your knowledge of what might be in your string (as with Nick Bull's solution), or accept a simpler solution where you maybe just capitalise the first letter and take the consequences.

(I know which I'd choose)

Comment: Which would you choose?

Comment: Partly because I'm lazy, partly because whatever list of exception words you choose someone is bound to use another one, I'd go for simply capitalising the first letter. 'Banana and apple' isn't going to disrupt a human reader for a moment - whereas we've seen the difficulties that it causes for programs. So I'd rely on the intuitive flexibility of humans rather than mess endlessly with possible combinations.